# Are problems appropriate here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a problem that I would like to see a solution for in java. I do not know how to code it, I would like to see an algorithm for it that works. Unfortunately in the past I have been asked to provide code whenever I ask for questions, which I saddly cannot provide, for I have no idea how to code a solution to the problem.

The question I have is the following:

> Consider the set [n]={1,2,3....n} and a positive integer k. Now
>   consider the set F of families of subsets of [n] exist such that:
>
> ```
> There are exactly k elements in F
> Subsets can appear more than once
> Each subset has an odd number of elements
> Two intersecting subsets A and B satisfy A⊆B or B⊆A
> Every element of [n] belongs to at least one of the subsets.
> ```
>
> We call two families A and B of F isomorphic if there is a bijection σ
>   of [n] such that every subset s of [n] appears with the same
>   multiplicity in A as σ(s) in B.
>
> How many different isomorphism types does F have?

Comment: You are asking for to do your work for you there, which is not an acceptable question. And anyway, you are asking for too much: 1. An algorithm. 2. An implementation in $language.

Comment: Are there sites on the stackexchange website where this problem would be acceptable? I mean in mathematics.stackexchange.com there would be no problem. Unfortunately this problem requires computer assistance. I have seen some site like for example code golfing do allow for questions in which no code must be supplied. And users seem to get a ton of code back in the answers. Is there a site for programming problems of this nature?

Answer (score 15):

No, asking for solutions to problems because you have no idea how to start solving them yourself is not appropriate here. This is a site for programmers to share their knowledge with each other, not to do work for people for free. It sounds like you need to either hire a programmer to work for you, or look at freelance sites where you can get people to do small projects for you.

Comment: ... or pay attention in class. Sounds like homework.

Comment: related: **[Where to start](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)**

Comment: @AndrewMedico it is not homework, I personally believe it is an extremely hard problem.